# ruby on rails incorrect default socket is /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

This is strange for me because when i run `sudo find / -type s`
the **mysql.sock** location is `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, the problem is when i start ruby using **`rail s`** an error came up

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

i know i could change `database.yml` file configuration by adding

```
socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

fix everthing but i was wondering why ruby's socket is pointed to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` when i have `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` when i run `sudo find / -type s`. Can someone explain why rails act like this and help me change ruby on rails default socket configuration to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Additional Info

When i run `ps -aef | grep mysql` mysql socket still points to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

I have tried to edit `my.cnf` under `/etc/mysql` since i dont have my.cnf in `tmp/my.cnf` and change socket to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a soft of file **/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock** to **/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock** by command:

```
ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

OR

change the socket file path in **my.cnf** or **my.ini** file.

Comment: sir i have tried editing my.cnf file but rails still looks for  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock file

Comment: rails always looks for this location, change the my.cnf file to this position so that rail get this file here..

Comment: thank for the help sir :) though you did not really explain why rails default socket is /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but it helps me somewhat change its default socket

Comment: not only rails but most of the application that connect to mysql have this default location of mysql socket file

Comment: I thought this solve my problem sir but when i open my pc today and start my rails project error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) and when i try to specify the socket inside database.yml file it will work but if i remove it error shows up

Comment: i noticed that the mysqld.sock that was created was gone

Comment: when i start the mysql ,the link file was not created this means that i need to create it every time i open my pc sir?

Comment: find mysqld.sock in whole server because may be its location changed .

Comment: what do you mean by no sir? and it will create automatically?